# Neo4j Random Relationships

Tags: neo4j

I have vertice v which has a lot of (millions) edges. Each time I query for a small subset of these edges (1K). I would like these edges to be different in each query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that (using Cypher):

```
MATCH (v:Foo)
WHERE v.id = 'node_with_millions_of_BAR_relationships'
WITH v, [(v)-[r:BAR]->() | r] AS rels
WITH v, rels, CASE WHEN $limit >= SIZE(rels)
  THEN 1.0
  ELSE TOFLOAT($limit) / SIZE(rels) END AS pct
RETURN v, CASE WHEN pct >= 1.0
  THEN rels
  ELSE REDUCE(s = [], x IN rels | CASE
    WHEN SIZE(s) < $limit AND rand() < pct THEN s + x
    ELSE s END)
  END AS randomRels
```

Assumptions made by this example:

- The (maximum) number of random relationships to return is specified by the `limit` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).
- The node of interest has the `Foo` label, and the relationships of interest are outgoing and have the `BAR` type.

Comment: In the worst case it will iterate over all edges?

Comment: Yes. If `limit < # of relationships`, this query will iterate over most (and sometimes all) of them in order to get a random sample from the entire set of relevant relationships.

Comment: but it is very slow, the matter is that limit is much smaller then number of rels